# PANDAS : Match two columns and return Index

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas. I am stuck at one problem. 
I have two Columns in Excel which I am modifying using PANDAS

```
0 ABC Yes
1 TZY No
2 KYZ No
3 HJO No
4 OAI Yes
5 PAU yes
```

I want to return all values with Yes using PANDAS
So here I want a list of all yes i.e. [ABC, OAI, PAU]

Please can anyone help me, I am new to Python.

Comment: Have you created the pandas DataFrame yet?  What are the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)

print(df)

    0   1   2
0   0   ABC Yes
1   1   TZY No
2   2   KYZ No
3   3   HJO No
4   4   OAI Yes
5   5   PAU yes

yes_list = ['Yes', 'yes']
df = df[df[2].isin(yes_list)]

print(df)


0   1   2
0   0   ABC Yes
4   4   OAI Yes
5   5   PAU yes
```

Here is some additional code for your edits, if you just want a list instead of a df slice.

```
yes_value_list = df[1].to_list()

print(yes_value_list)
['ABC', 'OAI', 'PAU']
```

Comment: `df.loc[df[2].str.lower() == 'yes', 1].tolist()` --> ['ABC', 'OAI', 'PAU']

Comment: Worked perfectly well!. Thanks a lot